# How to convert Google proto timestamp to Java LocalDate?

Tags: java, date, grpc, grpc-java, proto

We need to convert Google Proto buffer time stamp to a normal date. In that circumstance is there any way to convert Google Proto buffer timestamp to a Java `LocalDate` directly?

Comment: Do you mean by _Java8 Date_ `LocalDate`? `Date` itself is Java 1 :-)

Comment: Sorry Its typo. changed the question now @LuCio,

Comment: Actually Google Proto Buffer returning com.google.protobuf.Timestamp instance. In that place we need to convert it into LocalDate or what ever its !

Comment: Use `Instant.ofEpochSecond(yourTimestamp.getSeconds(), yourTimestamp.getNanos())` and continue from the `Instant` you get. If in doubt, search for how to convert `Instant` to `LocalDate`, it’s described in many places.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote to explain how this Question is not helpful, constructive, or well-formed. Seems  to me to be a perfectly fine Question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## tl;dr

As a moment in UTC, convert to `java.time.Instant`. Then apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Extract the date-only portion as a `LocalDate`.

One-liner:

```
Instant
.ofEpochSecond( ts.getSeconds() , ts.getNanos() ) 
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
.toLocalDate()
```

## Convert

First step is to convert the [`Timestamp`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Timestamp) object’s count of seconds and fractional second (nanoseconds) to the *java.time* classes. Specifically, [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Just like `Timestamp`, an `Instant` represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant =  Instant.ofEpochSecond( ts.getSeconds() , ts.getNanos() ) ;
```

Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

Apply a `ZoneId` to our `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion as a `LocalDate`. A `LocalDate` has no time-of-day and no time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Caution: Do *not* use `LocalDateTime` class for this purpose, as unfortunately shown in another Answer. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such it cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline. See class documentation.

## Convert

Best to entirely avoid the terribly troublesome legacy date-time classes including `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* you can convert back-and-forth. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

To represent a date-only value as a `GregorianCalendar` we must specify a time-of-day and a time zone. You’ll likely want to use the first moment of the day as the time-of-day component. Never assume the first moment is 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time mean the first moment might be another time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfDay = ld.atZone( z ) ;
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( firstMomentOfDay ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Basil Bourque  And can you please help me like how do we convert into Calendar instance too ( java.util.calendar)

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu I added “Convert” section.

Answer (score 1):

First some heads up: Protobuf's `TimeStamp` has a higher resolution (Seconds and fractions of seconds) than Java's `LocalDate` (Days) so you will be loosing some information by converting from `TimeStamp` to a `LocalDate`

See this excerpt of TimeStamp's [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
>   calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

---

This very same JavaDoc tells us, the value is a representation based on Epoch time, that means we can use Java's [LocalDateTime#ofEpochSeconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#ofEpochSecond-long-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-) to convert without loss (because `LocalDateTime` also stores time) and from there on strip the time to get a `LocalDate`.

By using a `LocalDateTime` (em: Local) we can make sure we use the same TimeZone offset as the `TimeStamp` Class does, which is UTC (thats again from the JavaDoc):

```
final Timestamp ts1 = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds((60 * 60 * 24) - 1).build();
final Timestamp ts2 = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds((60 * 60 * 24)).build();

final LocalDate ld1 = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(ts1.getSeconds(), ts1.getNanos(), ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
final LocalDate ld2 = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(ts2.getSeconds(), ts2.getNanos(), ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();

System.out.println(ts1 + " = " + ld1);
System.out.println(ts2 + " = " + ld2);
```

Output

> seconds: 86399  = 1970-01-01
>
> seconds: 86400  = 1970-01-02

---

**EDIT** after asking for conversion to `java.util.Date`

Looking at possible constructors for `Date` and their [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) we find:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

And because GMT beeing the older Standard for zoned time representation and it is basically UTC +/- 0, this constructor fits our needs:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// making sure the Date objects use UTC as timezone

final Timestamp ts1 = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds((60 * 60 * 24) - 1).build();
final Timestamp ts2 = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds((60 * 60 * 24)).build();

final Date d1 = new Date(ts1.getSeconds() * 1000);
final Date d2 = new Date(ts2.getSeconds() * 1000);

System.out.println(ts1 + " = " + d1);
System.out.println(ts2 + " = " + d2);
```

Output:

> seconds: 86399 = Thu Jan 01 23:59:59 CET 1970
>
> seconds: 86400 = Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 1970

Comment: And more thing like is there any way to convert java.util.Date from proto timestamp instead of LocalDate.

Comment: **Incorrect.** `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to be using here. That class cannot represent a moment, as explained in its class documentation. That class represents a range of *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe). Instead, use `java.time.Instant` to represent a moment in UTC.

Comment: @BasilBourque I agree that `Instant` would be more elegant by hiding all the epoch/time zone stuff, though it would not be that much of an explanation to OP of what exactly happens. You are right saying that `LocalDateTime` _can_ represent a range. But by specifying the time zone offset non of that matters. That would be the same as saying don't use `int` for numbers between `0` and `10`, because `int` can also be `10.000`.

Comment: @BasilBourque and could you please provide an example where my conversion aproach doesn't work? Because I am really open to learn new things and that would be a justification for the downvote and the bold 'incorrect' labeling. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
long millis = com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps.toMillis(protoTimestamp);

LocalDate result = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

see @ https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps.html#toMillis-com.google.protobuf.Timestamp-

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to extract the date from the buffer Timestamp to a **String** so it can be multiused and then:

```
Timestamp timestamp;
String sDate1 = timestamp.toString();  
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1);
```

In case you want to make it a LocalDate you do the following:

```
Timestamp timestamp;
String sDate1 = timestamp.toString();    
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(sDate1);
```

In case you cannot extract the String timestamp and you have Miliseconds you can also create the LocalDate and Date object from that as well, as they both have contractors for it.

```
    Timestamp timestamp;
    long timeInMilliSeconds = Timestamp.toMillis(timestamp);
    Date currentDate = new Date(timeInMilliSeconds);
    LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMilliSeconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Actually Google Proto Buffer returning com.google.protobuf.Timestamp instance. In that place we need to convert it into LocalDate or what ever its !

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu there has to be a way to make the timestamp a String. After you manage that it is very easy to do whatever you want with it

Comment: Actually google proto buffter timestamp returning the below value     seconds: 988221139
nanos: 516000000

Comment: Can you pls check com.google.protobuf.Timestamp class ? @hedgehog

Comment: i did and i saw that both toString and getMili exists. i edited my answer, refresh and check @Thirunavukkarasu

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu use this and you will be fine: LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMilliSeconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

Comment: I'm using com.google.protobuf.Timestamp not com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu just go in here and see the methods that we are telling you. com.google.protobuf.Timestamp  , toSeconds(), toNanoSeconds() is there. USE THEM!!!

Comment: @OleV.V. As you can see i have different examples for Date and LocalDate, I only added date for future reference to others getting help from this post.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Timestamp) there is no `getTime` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = message.getPubsubMessage();
String data = pubsubMessage.getData().toStringUtf8();
//System.out.println(pubsubMessage.getMessageId());
Timestamp timestamp = pubsubMessage.getPublishTime();
//System.out.println(timestamp);
Instant instant =  Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp.getSeconds() , 
timestamp.getNanos());
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal");
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(z);
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println("today's date==> "+ldt.getDayOfMonth());
```

The above code will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Are you contributing much that isn’t already in the other answers? It’s more the explanations that we learn from, so if you could add some, please? I believe that your code works.